# Show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\mu (\{|f|\ge n\})}<\infty$ iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}\int_{E}{f^2\Bbb{1}_{\{|f|\leq n\}}d\mu}}<\infty$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu) $ be a finite measure space. Let $f \in \mathcal {L}_{\mathbb{R}}^{1}(\mu)$ . show that the following assertions :

$(i)$. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\mu (\{|f|\geq n\})}<\infty$.

$(ii)$. $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac {1}{n^2}\int_{E}{f^2\mathbb{1}_{\{|f|\leq n\}}d\mu}}< \infty$.

are equivalent

An idea please .

Comment: Hello! Please provide some context for this problem with an [edit]. Where does this problem come from? What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far, and where did that fail?

Comment: I have no idea only I proposed that: $ |f|=|f|\mathbb {1}_{|f|>n}+|f|\mathbb {1}_{|f|\leq n}$

Comment: @Brain, an idea please

Comment: Hint: $\int_E f^2 1_{\{|f|\le n\}}=\int_{\{|f|\le n\}} f^2\le \int_{\{|f|\le n\}}n^2$

Comment: Thanks, This Hint did not help me,

Answer (score 1):

(i) is equivalent to f being in $L^1$.

$$\int |f| d\mu = \int \sum_n |f|1\{n\leq |f| <n+1\} d\mu\geq\sum_n \int n  1\{n\leq |f| <n+1\} d\mu = \sum_n n\mu(n\leq |f| <n+1) = \sum_n \mu(|f| \geq n )$$ The reverse equivalence is achieved by taking the $\leq n+1$ approach above.

(ii) is a similarly shown by breaking into intervals. I can outline it but you seem to only want a hint and not the full answer. Comment below and I can show.

Comment: Thanks, but i want equivalent between  $(i) $ and $(ii) $

Comment: I am saying (ii) is equivalent to being in $L^1$ so (i) is equivalent to (ii) by transitivity of equivalence. I just haven't spelt out how (ii) is equivalent to being in $L^1$ in detail.

Comment: so i only want an idea to show if $ f $ is integrable then $ (ii) $ is true

Comment: Exact same splitting as first one. Use Caffeines hint to get the necessary inequality.

Comment: I apologize, sir, I have shown that if $ f $ is integrable then $ (ii) $ is true. I want to show that if $ (ii) $ is true then $ f $ is integrable.